# What does QSL mean in a CW conversation?

Tags: cw

When the other party sends `QSL`, do they just want to know whether I received the previous message and expect `RR` or `AGN?` Or, are they asking for a `QSL Card` to be sent to them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally, QSL means "I acknowledge receipt".

"QSL?" (with a question mark) means "please acknowledge".

Sometimes when listening to QSOs you will hear someone say QSL VIA BURO or QSL DIRECT or similar, and those are instructions on how to send a QSL card. But QSL on its own just means "acknowledged".

Finally, if someone says PSE QSL then *that* usually means that they would like a QSL card.

Answer (score 8):

Especially true in a contest, or noisy environment:

Hearing a "QSL?" from someone can mean they want to know specifically if what *they've sent to you* has been sent correctly. They may have been trying to pull your callsign out of the QRN or QRM and want to ONLY hear back from you a "QSL" or "R" so they can confidently log your call. If you hear correct information (say,  your call) followed by a **QSL?** absolutely DO NOT SEND YOUR INFORMATION AGAIN. Doing so is a tacit indication that they DO NOT have the information correct.  And, yes, QSL is often used on phone regardless of what the purists might advise!

HIM  **CQ CQ**

YOU  **W1^%&**   (as heard by HIM)

HIM **W1? AGN?**

YOU  ***&ABC**   (as heard by HIM)

HIM  **W1ABC QSL QSL??**

YOU  **QSL QSL QSL**